# How to get a related objects queryset through multiple levels of reverse foreignkeys in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have a model of the sort:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    ...

class Author(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Article(models.Model):
    author= models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I'm trying to get all the articles from a given publisher 'pub'.
I've tried doing the following:

> pub.article_set()
>
> pub.authot_set().article_set()

As well as other failed tentatives. So how can I retrieve a Queryset of all articles of a given publisher without hitting the database too many times? Whats the most efficient way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient way to reduce number of database queries will be to filter on the queryset of Articles.

```
# pub is the instance of Publisher
articles = Article.objects.filter(author__publisher=pub)
```